# Making CSS template with Flash work in ASP.Net MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, flash

I want to integrate this template in my mvc application (visual studio):

http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page131/calliope#bookmarks

I manage to make the entire index page load correctly exactly as in the live demo, and do what I want, the only thing that refuses to work properly is the flash element (the thing that scrolls through different items on a timer, and with arrows).

The furthest I get is the red Cuber logo appears indicating that the flash is loading, but that's the end of it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since you can write some web standards on your `Views`, `Layout`, `PartialViews`, you can do anything you want on the client side. The ASP.NET MVC will not avoid you to write some tags to add flash component on your page, it will work with the browser.